# How to plot hazard function for coxme object?

Tags: r, mixed-models, survival-analysis, cox-regression, hazard

Using the `bshazard()`, I can plot a hazard curve as follows:

```
# Model Fit
fit <- bshazard(Surv(enter, exit, event) ~ 1, df)

# Plot
df_surv <- data.frame(time = fit$time, hazard = fit$hazard,
                      lower.ci = fit$lower.ci, upper.ci = fit$upper.ci)

ggplot(df_surv, aes(x = time, y = hazard)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower.ci, ymax = upper.ci), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image: this]

How do I get a similar plot using a `coxme` model like the following?

```
fit <- coxme(Surv(exit, event) ~ sex + (1 | id), df)
```